Phusion Passenger does not start in ubuntu startup with nginx
After rebooting my EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18, I expect Phusion Passenger to be up and running automatically. However, this is not happening. I have to manually start it running passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d  -e production.
This is my nginx VH config:
server {
    server_name myserver.com www.myserver.com;
    root /var/www/cooperativa-frontend/cooperativa/www;
    index index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/cooperativa-frontend/cooperativa/www;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Configure API endpoint with Passenger
    location /api/v1/ {
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;  # Set Rails environment if necessary
        root /var/www/cooperativa-api/public;
        passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/wrappers/ruby;

        # Proxy pass to Rails application (adjust as per your setup)
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Adjust additional proxy settings if necessary
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # SSL configuration
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/odontologia-integral.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/odontologia-integral.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Security headers (optional, adjust as per your needs)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://localhost:3000' always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name odontologia-integral.com www.odontologia-integral.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    # Certbot will manage further configuration
}

Any ideas about why this might be happening?
